# Calling Fortran code from julia, accessing array dynamically allocated in fortran

Tags: fortran, julia

I need to call some fortran code that dynamically allocates arrays similar to this basic example. (unlike this example in the code I'm working with the size of the array is not known at the beginning of the function)

```
subroutine getIdentity(n,I)
    integer, intent(in) :: n
    integer, allocatable,dimension(:,:), intent(out) :: I
    integer :: j,k
    write(*,*) "creating " ,n, "x", n, "identity matrix"

    allocate(I(n,n))

    do j=1,n
        do k=1,n
        if(k==j) then
            I(j,k) = 1
        else
            I(j,k) = 0
        end if
    end do
    end do
end subroutine getIdentity
```

When I call this with this julia code:

```
I = zeros(Int32,1,1)
n = Ref{Int32}(3)
ccall((:__myModule_MOD_getidentity,"./test.so"), Cvoid ,
      (Ref{Int32},Ref{Int32}), n,I)
println(I)
```

When I look at I in julia it is just garbage, not the Identity matrix I would expect. What would be the correct way to do this?

Comment: Can you alter the subroutine source to make it C interoperable?  And if so, is that useful?

Comment: Do you know any Fortran?  What does `intent(out)` do to an allocatable array on entry to a subprogram?

Comment: @Steve I didn't realize that the array was automatically deallocated when entering the subroutine,  however I'm still getting the same behavior when changing it to `intent(inout)`.

Comment: @francescalus I have tried that by adding bind(c) to the subroutine declaration, but didn't see any change

Comment: I don't use Julia (although Julia uses my code!), so this is just a guess.  Try changing the declaration for `I` to an explicit shaped array.  `INTEGER, INTENT(INOUT) :: I(N,N)`.  One other thing that you might need is the `VALUE` attribute.

Comment: @Steve I am able to get statically sized arrays working just fine, my example wasn't the best because you can know the dimensions of the array at the beginning of the subroutine. The actual code I'm working on requires dynamically allocated arrays.

Comment: You'll need to do more than add `bind(c)`: that makes the subroutine interoperable (assuming default integers are interoperable) but you'll need to then call the subroutine in an interoperable way.  I can't, alas, tell you how to do that in Julia like I can with C.